[How to run only particular APIs in a collection of APIs
In my collection I have many requests with asserts, in that I need to run only particular requests.  Assume I have 10 requests and I need to run only 3,4 & 10 how can I do it by running through the newman in command line.
Scenario:
In the below collection I have multiple requests (marked in different colors).  Assume in our application there is a new build in which it impacts only the requests that are marked in "Yellow".  In this case I want to run only the requests that are marked in Yellow.
enter image description here

Hi Stephen, please consider improving your question with your research efforts. Try to pinpoint your exact problem. This will allow the community to serve you a better answer. By the way, a postman collection contains requests, not APIs ;-).

@PixelPlex I have updated the questions with more details... thanks for your response

You can do it by "pm.execution.skipRequest()" in Pre-request Script with if statement.
Example:
This Script decide by Color value.
If Green or All color, run request.
If Yellow or Red color, skip request.
const color = pm.environment.get('Color');
if (color != "Green" && color != "All") {
    pm.execution.skipRequest();
}

Demo
I will using Animal GET API by animal name with color prefix
Total 8 requests
It includes 4 Yellow Request, 3 Green Requests and 1 Red Request.
If set the Color is Yellow, call only 4 Yellow Requests.
If set the Color is Green, call only 3 Green Requests.
If set the Color is Red, call only 1 Red Request.
If set the Color is All, call all 8 Requests.
Animal URL
https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=[Animal Name]


First Request

Defined Environment Variable as "Color"

Demo collection JSON file.
Save as 1-demo.postman_collection.json
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "2425762f-9acf-4ca9-b3e7-96a6be66ffea",
        "name": "1-demo",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json",
        "_exporter_id": "2207020"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "Yellow Get Lion",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "console.log(jsonData[0].name);\r",
                            "pm.test('Animal = ' + jsonData[0].name, function () {\r",
                            "    pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(\"Lion\");\r",
                            "});"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const color = pm.environment.get('Color');\r",
                            "console.log(\"run request color: \" + color);\r",
                            "\r",
                            "if (color != \"Yellow\" && color != \"All\") {\r",
                            "    pm.execution.skipRequest();\r",
                            "}"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Key",
                        "value": "1956f59b5msh089630402391f02p108b9bjsna7adb689e8c4",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Host",
                        "value": "gemini-pro-vision-ai1.p.rapidapi.com",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=Lion",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "freetestapi",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "v1",
                        "animals"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "search",
                            "value": "Lion"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Green Get Elephant",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "console.log(jsonData[0].name);\r",
                            "pm.test('Animal = ' + jsonData[0].name, function () {\r",
                            "    pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(\"Elephant\");\r",
                            "});"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const color = pm.environment.get('Color');\r",
                            "if (color != \"Green\" && color != \"All\") {\r",
                            "    pm.execution.skipRequest();\r",
                            "}"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Key",
                        "value": "1956f59b5msh089630402391f02p108b9bjsna7adb689e8c4",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Host",
                        "value": "gemini-pro-vision-ai1.p.rapidapi.com",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=Elephant",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "freetestapi",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "v1",
                        "animals"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "search",
                            "value": "Elephant"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Yellow Get Tiger",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "console.log(jsonData[0].name);\r",
                            "pm.test('Animal = ' + jsonData[0].name, function () {\r",
                            "    pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(\"Tiger\");\r",
                            "});"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const color = pm.environment.get('Color');\r",
                            "if (color != \"Yellow\" && color != \"All\") {\r",
                            "    pm.execution.skipRequest();\r",
                            "}"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Key",
                        "value": "1956f59b5msh089630402391f02p108b9bjsna7adb689e8c4",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Host",
                        "value": "gemini-pro-vision-ai1.p.rapidapi.com",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=Tiger",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "freetestapi",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "v1",
                        "animals"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "search",
                            "value": "Tiger"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Green Get Kangaroo",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "console.log(jsonData[0].name);\r",
                            "pm.test('Animal = ' + jsonData[0].name, function () {\r",
                            "    pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(\"Kangaroo\");\r",
                            "});"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const color = pm.environment.get('Color');\r",
                            "if (color != \"Green\"  && color != \"All\") {\r",
                            "    pm.execution.skipRequest();\r",
                            "}"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Key",
                        "value": "1956f59b5msh089630402391f02p108b9bjsna7adb689e8c4",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Host",
                        "value": "gemini-pro-vision-ai1.p.rapidapi.com",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=Kangaroo",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "freetestapi",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "v1",
                        "animals"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "search",
                            "value": "Kangaroo"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Yellow Get Gorilla",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "console.log(jsonData[0].name);\r",
                            "pm.test('Animal = ' + jsonData[0].name, function () {\r",
                            "    pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(\"Gorilla\");\r",
                            "});"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const color = pm.environment.get('Color');\r",
                            "if (color != \"Yellow\" && color != \"All\") {\r",
                            "    pm.execution.skipRequest();\r",
                            "}"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Key",
                        "value": "1956f59b5msh089630402391f02p108b9bjsna7adb689e8c4",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Host",
                        "value": "gemini-pro-vision-ai1.p.rapidapi.com",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=Gorilla",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "freetestapi",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "v1",
                        "animals"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "search",
                            "value": "Gorilla"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Green Get Polar Bear",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "console.log(jsonData[0].name);\r",
                            "pm.test('Animal = ' + jsonData[0].name, function () {\r",
                            "    pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(\"Polar Bear\");\r",
                            "});"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const color = pm.environment.get('Color');\r",
                            "if (color != \"Green\" && color != \"All\") {\r",
                            "    pm.execution.skipRequest();\r",
                            "}"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Key",
                        "value": "1956f59b5msh089630402391f02p108b9bjsna7adb689e8c4",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Host",
                        "value": "gemini-pro-vision-ai1.p.rapidapi.com",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=Polar%20Bear",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "freetestapi",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "v1",
                        "animals"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "search",
                            "value": "Polar%20Bear"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Yellow Get Koala",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "console.log(jsonData[0].name);\r",
                            "pm.test('Animal = ' + jsonData[0].name, function () {\r",
                            "    pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(\"Koala\");\r",
                            "});"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const color = pm.environment.get('Color');\r",
                            "if (color != \"Yellow\" && color != \"All\") {\r",
                            "    pm.execution.skipRequest();\r",
                            "}"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Key",
                        "value": "1956f59b5msh089630402391f02p108b9bjsna7adb689e8c4",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Host",
                        "value": "gemini-pro-vision-ai1.p.rapidapi.com",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=Koala",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "freetestapi",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "v1",
                        "animals"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "search",
                            "value": "Koala"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Red Get Giraffe",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "console.log(jsonData[0].name);\r",
                            "pm.test('Animal = ' + jsonData[0].name, function () {\r",
                            "    pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(\"Giraffe\");\r",
                            "});"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const color = pm.environment.get('Color');\r",
                            "if (color != \"Red\" && color != \"All\") {\r",
                            "    pm.execution.skipRequest();\r",
                            "}"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Key",
                        "value": "1956f59b5msh089630402391f02p108b9bjsna7adb689e8c4",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Host",
                        "value": "gemini-pro-vision-ai1.p.rapidapi.com",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=Giraffe",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "freetestapi",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "v1",
                        "animals"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "search",
                            "value": "Giraffe"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ],
    "event": [
        {
            "listen": "prerequest",
            "script": {
                "type": "text/javascript",
                "packages": {},
                "exec": [
                    ""
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "listen": "test",
            "script": {
                "type": "text/javascript",
                "packages": {},
                "exec": [
                    ""
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

Run it by Newman
Run Green Requests Only
newman run 1-demo.postman_collection.json --env-var "Color=Green"


Run Yellow Requests Only
newman run 1-demo.postman_collection.json --env-var "Color=Yellow"


Run All Requests
newman run 1-demo.postman_collection.json --env-var "Color=All"



Multiple Selection
This sub string check by includes() can do it.
const color = pm.environment.get('Color');

if (!color.includes("Green") && color != "All") {
    pm.execution.skipRequest();
}

Save as 2-demo.postman_collection.json
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "fdad8514-6cb4-43e8-94ba-f96026c29822",
        "name": "3-demo",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json",
        "_exporter_id": "1826150"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "Yellow Get Lion",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "console.log(jsonData[0].name);\r",
                            "pm.test('Animal = ' + jsonData[0].name, function () {\r",
                            "    pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(\"Lion\");\r",
                            "});"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const color = pm.environment.get('Color');\r",
                            "console.log(\"run request color: \" + color);\r",
                            "\r",
                            "if (!color.includes(\"Yellow\") && color != \"All\") {\r",
                            "    pm.execution.skipRequest();\r",
                            "}"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Key",
                        "value": "1956f59b5msh089630402391f02p108b9bjsna7adb689e8c4",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Host",
                        "value": "gemini-pro-vision-ai1.p.rapidapi.com",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=Lion",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "freetestapi",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "v1",
                        "animals"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "search",
                            "value": "Lion"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Green Get Elephant",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "if (jsonData) {\r",
                            "    console.log(jsonData[0].name);\r",
                            "    pm.test('Animal = ' + jsonData[0].name, function () {\r",
                            "        pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(\"Elephant\");\r",
                            "    });\r",
                            "}\r",
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const color = pm.environment.get('Color');\r",
                            "\r",
                            "if (!color.includes(\"Green\") && color != \"All\") {\r",
                            "    pm.execution.skipRequest();\r",
                            "}"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Key",
                        "value": "1956f59b5msh089630402391f02p108b9bjsna7adb689e8c4",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Host",
                        "value": "gemini-pro-vision-ai1.p.rapidapi.com",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=Elephant",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "freetestapi",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "v1",
                        "animals"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "search",
                            "value": "Elephant"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Yellow Get Tiger",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "console.log(jsonData[0].name);\r",
                            "pm.test('Animal = ' + jsonData[0].name, function () {\r",
                            "    pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(\"Tiger\");\r",
                            "});"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const color = pm.environment.get('Color');\r",
                            "\r",
                            "if (!color.includes(\"Yellow\") && color != \"All\") {\r",
                            "    pm.execution.skipRequest();\r",
                            "}"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Key",
                        "value": "1956f59b5msh089630402391f02p108b9bjsna7adb689e8c4",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Host",
                        "value": "gemini-pro-vision-ai1.p.rapidapi.com",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=Tiger",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "freetestapi",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "v1",
                        "animals"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "search",
                            "value": "Tiger"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Green Get Kangaroo",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "if (jsonData) {\r",
                            "    console.log(jsonData[0].name);\r",
                            "    pm.test('Animal = ' + jsonData[0].name, function () {\r",
                            "        pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(\"Kangaroo\");\r",
                            "    });\r",
                            "}\r",
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const color = pm.environment.get('Color');\r",
                            "\r",
                            "if (!color.includes(\"Green\") && color != \"All\") {\r",
                            "    pm.execution.skipRequest();\r",
                            "}"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Key",
                        "value": "1956f59b5msh089630402391f02p108b9bjsna7adb689e8c4",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Host",
                        "value": "gemini-pro-vision-ai1.p.rapidapi.com",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=Kangaroo",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "freetestapi",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "v1",
                        "animals"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "search",
                            "value": "Kangaroo"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Yellow Get Gorilla",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "console.log(jsonData[0].name);\r",
                            "pm.test('Animal = ' + jsonData[0].name, function () {\r",
                            "    pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(\"Gorilla\");\r",
                            "});"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const color = pm.environment.get('Color');\r",
                            "\r",
                            "if (!color.includes(\"Yellow\") && color != \"All\") {\r",
                            "    pm.execution.skipRequest();\r",
                            "}"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Key",
                        "value": "1956f59b5msh089630402391f02p108b9bjsna7adb689e8c4",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Host",
                        "value": "gemini-pro-vision-ai1.p.rapidapi.com",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=Gorilla",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "freetestapi",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "v1",
                        "animals"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "search",
                            "value": "Gorilla"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Green Get Polar Bear",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "if (jsonData) {\r",
                            "    console.log(jsonData[0].name);\r",
                            "    pm.test('Animal = ' + jsonData[0].name, function () {\r",
                            "        pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(\"Polar Bear\");\r",
                            "    });\r",
                            "}\r",
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const color = pm.environment.get('Color');\r",
                            "\r",
                            "if (!color.includes(\"Green\") && color != \"All\") {\r",
                            "    pm.execution.skipRequest();\r",
                            "}"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Key",
                        "value": "1956f59b5msh089630402391f02p108b9bjsna7adb689e8c4",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Host",
                        "value": "gemini-pro-vision-ai1.p.rapidapi.com",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=Polar Bear",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "freetestapi",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "v1",
                        "animals"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "search",
                            "value": "Polar Bear"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Yellow Get Koala",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "console.log(jsonData[0].name);\r",
                            "pm.test('Animal = ' + jsonData[0].name, function () {\r",
                            "    pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(\"Koala\");\r",
                            "});"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const color = pm.environment.get('Color');\r",
                            "\r",
                            "if (!color.includes(\"Yellow\") && color != \"All\") {\r",
                            "    pm.execution.skipRequest();\r",
                            "}"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Key",
                        "value": "1956f59b5msh089630402391f02p108b9bjsna7adb689e8c4",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Host",
                        "value": "gemini-pro-vision-ai1.p.rapidapi.com",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=Koala",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "freetestapi",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "v1",
                        "animals"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "search",
                            "value": "Koala"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Red Get Giraffe",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "console.log(jsonData[0].name);\r",
                            "pm.test('Animal = ' + jsonData[0].name, function () {\r",
                            "    pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(\"Giraffe\");\r",
                            "});"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const color = pm.environment.get('Color');\r",
                            "\r",
                            "if (!color.includes(\"Red\") && color != \"All\") {\r",
                            "    pm.execution.skipRequest();\r",
                            "}"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Key",
                        "value": "1956f59b5msh089630402391f02p108b9bjsna7adb689e8c4",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "X-RapidAPI-Host",
                        "value": "gemini-pro-vision-ai1.p.rapidapi.com",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search=Giraffe",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "freetestapi",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "v1",
                        "animals"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "search",
                            "value": "Giraffe"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ],
    "event": [
        {
            "listen": "prerequest",
            "script": {
                "type": "text/javascript",
                "packages": {},
                "exec": [
                    ""
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "listen": "test",
            "script": {
                "type": "text/javascript",
                "packages": {},
                "exec": [
                    ""
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

Example
newman run 2-demo.postman_collection.json --env-var "Color=YellowGreen"

Will call 7 Request

newman run 2-demo.postman_collection.json --env-var "Color=YellowGreenRed"

Will call 8 Request


Thanks for your wonderful explanation, this really helps.  Also, one more issue is, if we need to send multiple selection assume "Green", "Yellow"  & "Red at the same time mean how to pass through the environment variable mean how to do it.  Since in our scenario we will have more than 30 options to pass through the environment variables then... please suggest

I updated support for multiple options. Can you try it with 2-demo.postman_collection.json?
